# Guava CharMatcher remove whitespace retain linebreaks

Tags: java, guava

Noob question, I need to split a string by many separators, and I want to delete all whitespaces, but Guava Charmatcher is removing linebreaks too (and linebreak is one of the separators):

```
Iterable<String> splittedRuts = Splitter.onPattern("\r?\n|,|/|;")
            .omitEmptyStrings()
            .split(CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.removeFrom(formList));
```

Comment: If you had followed through the definition of [`CharMatcher.WHITESPACE`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#WHITESPACE) from Guava itself, you'd understand why this happens...

Comment: Yeah, I read that and I know I should not use WHITESPACE, my question is how to do it. Not why it doesn't work.

Comment: So, why not just `Splitter.on(Pattern.compile"[,/;]"))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're ok with only removing the normal space character, you can just use `CharMatcher.is(' ')`.

Also, you may want to look at `Splitter.trimResults()` if your reason for wanting to strip whitespace is that you end up with leading or trailing whitespace when splitting.